# Save a dataframe view after groupBy using pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My homework is giving me a hard time with pyspark. I have this view of my "df2" after a groupBy:

```
 df2.groupBy('years').count().show()
+-----+-----+
|years|count|
+-----+-----+
| 2003|11904|
| 2006| 3476|
| 1997| 3979|
| 2004|13362|
| 1996| 3180|
| 1998| 4969|
| 1995| 1995|
| 2001|11532|
| 2005|11389|
| 2000| 7462|
| 1999| 6593|
| 2002|11799|
+-----+-----+
```

Every attempt to save this (and then load with pandas) to a file gives back the original source data text file form I read with pypspark with its original columns and attributes, only now its .csv but that's not the point.
What can I do to overcome this ?
For your concern I do not use SparkContext  function in the begining of the code, just plain "read" and "groupBy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df2.groupBy('years').count().write.csv("sample.csv")`

or

```
df3=df2.groupBy('years').count()
df3.write.csv("sample.csv")
```

both of them will create `sample.csv` in your working directory

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the results into a new dataframe `results`, and then write the results to a `csv` file. Note that there are two ways to output the csv. If you use spark you need to use `.coalesce(1)` to make sure only one file is outputted. The other way is to convert `.toPandas()` and use `to_csv()` function of pandas DataFrame.

```py
results = df2.groupBy('years').count()

# writes a csv file "part-xxx.csv" inside a folder "results"
results.coalesce(1).write.csv("results", header=True)

# or if you want a csv file, not a csv file inside a folder (default behaviour of spark)
results.toPandas().to_csv("results.csv")
```